# Hamburger icon made with css not opening menu in iphone

Tags: html, css

I have made a full page overlay menu that is displayed when click on the custom made icon. Its working fine on Android devices and in chrome inspector it works fine for all devices but when I test it on actual iPhone device menu doesn't appear.

Here is the screenshot of the icon before clicking it display like this :

[image]

When we click on it, display menu like this:

[image]

This menu is opened on iPhone x in chrome responsive tool but when I open it on actual iPhone device it didn't open.
I have tried a fix of adding onclick=void(0) like this

HTML Code

```
 <div id="nav-icon2" onclick = "void(0)">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 #nav-icon2 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon2 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #d3531a;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(even) {
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 9px 9px 0;
}

#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(odd) {
  left:0px;
  border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px;
}

#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(1), #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(3), #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(5), #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(6) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(1),#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 5px;
  top: 7px;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(2) {
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  top: 7px;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(3) {
  left: -50%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(4) {
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(5) {
  left: 5px;
  top: 29px;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(6) {
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  top: 29px;
}
```

JS:

```
    $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon2').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

But it didn't work for me. Here is my code for custom hamburger icon
[Demo](https://codepen.io/Sameed-Ul-Hassan/pen/KEaPpz)

Please, help me what's the problem I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: Please **edt** and add your CSS code to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @Martin you can check complete code on demo link I have created a pen on codepen. I also updated my question